# Seemingly odd exterior door jamb size

Tags: wood, wood-selection, door

I am going to replace a rotted piece of a exterior door jamb for a friend. The best I can measure, it *seems* to be, 2-3/8" (or 2-1/2"?) x 1-1/4". I probably need to do some taking apart to be sure, but I cannot find any wood listed in that size. I do have a piece of 2-3/8" (well maybe 2-1/2") x 1-1/2" and maybe that is what it really is. Thoughts?

Only photo I have at this time.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like time to do some **woodworking** to make the board you need.... Please share with us information about what tools and skills you have to work with. We can't really answer such an open-ended question otherwise.

Comment: I am moderately skilled, as in 'handyman level' woodworking... as in, this project doesn't scare me, but I really have no proper major tools for 'real woodworking', i.e., table saw, jigs, etc... (Unfortunately, the lady's husband had a fantastic shop, but he passed several months ago and his good equipment is already gone.) I'll make a cut on the wood to be replaced, probably with an oscillating saw, and see what I'm actually dealing with.

Comment: A hand plane can be used in a pinch to to do a little dimensioning,  but you might want to think about starting to collect some power tools if you plan to do a bit of these small jobs, You could have been done with the job in the time you spent asking your question here!  A jointer/planer and a table saw will allow you to not ever worry about odd sizes again.

Comment: You might get lucky and find enough airspace between the jamb and the rough framing to use a 2x. Assuming a short section and not the whole thing, a circular saw (and clamps!) with a bit of chisel will take 1/4” or so off pretty quick.

Comment: Not sure where you are in the world, but have you explored the possibility of finding a local maker's group or such that would let you use some tools for a few minutes?  Or a neighbor with a table saw? On the other hand, it's hard to think of many tools I own that weren't acquired to tackle a specific job...

Comment: @bowlturner, I'm totally giggling at the *"A hand plane can be used **in a pinch** to to do a little dimensioning*" :-D

Comment: @Graphus words can be just as fun as wood for building....

Comment: @bowlturner, :-)))